# Erlang: Location of *.hrl files in multiple applications

Tags: erlang, records

I'm developing a series of related applications that will eventually be integrated into a single release. Several of the applications share identical record structures.

Should I:

a) Duplicate the *.hrl files that define the record structure in the include directory of each of the applications?
b) Put a single file somewhere else in my application tree--- and, if so where?

Here's my current tree:

```
zpt$
   apps
       app1
          ebin
          include
             myrecords.hrl
          priv
          src
       app2
          ebin
          include
             myrecords.hrl
          priv
          src
       etc
```

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach I tried was to create an application which doesn't do anything, but contains the record definitions common to multiple projects.  Then I used rebar to include it as a dependency.  When including the hrl files, I use the `include_lib` syntax.  That syntax allows you to include hrl files from another application.

```
app
    ebin
    include
    priv
    src
        some_src.erl
    deps
        common_hrl_app
            include
                common_records.hrl
            src
            ebin
        other_dep_app
            src
                other_src.erl
            .
            .
            .
```

`include_lib` example which could appear in either some_src.erl or other_src.erl:

```
-include_lib("common_hrl_app/include/common_records.hrl").
```

I like this approach because:

1. It plays nicely with the rebar dependency system
2. It allows me to track the hrls in one place in version control
3. I can version this application, which allows me to pull specific versions if I want a new application to be compatible with another using the same records.

---

Answering questions from the comments:

I have a skeleton app file in the ebin directory which specifies the name and version of the application so rebar can verify the version.  Here's an example

```
{application,common_hrl_app,
         [{description,[]},
          {vsn,"1"},
          {registered,[]},
          {applications,[kernel,stdlib]},
          {env,[]},
          {modules,[]}]}.
```

With rebar, you have the top level application, which can have multiple applications as dependencies.  When rebar fetches these dependencies, it places them in the deps directory.  If any of those applications has their own dependencies, those are also fetched to the deps directory, and so on.  There isn't an infinitely nested hierarchy of deps directories.

Comment: This looks like a cool solution. But I'm unclear about a couple of things, perhaps because I'm still a bit shaky with Rebar: 1) Are all but the include directory empty in the common_hrl_app? 2) Does the deps subtree go into every other application in my tree?

Comment: Added some clarification to the answer.